# This is not a byte by byte comparison: WHY

Tags: c, loops, pointers, byte, infinite

I would like to take two files, compare them byte-by-byte, and test it's performance,

So far, this is what my code looks like:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp1, *fp2;
    int ch1, ch2;
    char fname1[40], fname2[40] ;

    printf("Enter name of first file :") ;
    gets(fname1);

    printf("Enter name of second file:");
    gets(fname2);

    clock();    

    fp1 = fopen( fname1,  "r" );
    fp2 = fopen( fname2,  "r" ) ;

    if ( fp1 == NULL )
    {
        printf("Cannot open %s for reading\n", fname1 );
        exit(1);
    }
    else if (fp2 == NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot open %s for reading\n", fname2 );
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        ch1  =  getc( fp1 ) ;
        ch2  =  getc( fp2 ) ;

        while( (ch1!=EOF) && (ch2!=EOF) && (ch1 == ch2))
        {
            ch1 = getc(fp1);
            ch2 = getc(fp2);
        }

        if (ch1 == ch2)
            printf("Files are identical\n");
        else if (ch1 != ch2)
            printf("Files are Not identical\n");

        fclose ( fp1 );
        fclose ( fp2 );
    }

    printf("That took %d seconds.\n", clock() / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    return 0;
}
```

I was told: "==" is NOT a byte-by-byte comparison, how can I implement this so that I can XOR bitwise operations?

Also, is there a way to check how much duplication is in a single file itself?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: You're probably not concerned about this, but just an FYI, it's not really possible in strictly-conforming C, since binary files are allowed to have an arbitrary number of null bytes after the end of the file.

Comment: @DrewMcGowen ok, hmm what about printing out at which bytes or points the files are not identical?

Comment: You can just have a counter that increments after every comparison; however, you'd have to compare byte-by-byte to accurately detect where the differences are

Comment: @DrewMcGowen also, how would it work by using the minimum of read1 and read2? I am not sure what part of the code to fix

Comment: Well, it's not really relevant now, considering your latest edit

Comment: @DrewMcGowen ok, that what I was trying to figure out, so this isn't really a byte-by-byte comparison then? Would I have to implement that using XOR bitwise operations?

Comment: This code does do byte-by-byte comparison on text files. (open with `"rb"` to do that for non-text files). IDK what you are talking about with "XOR bitwise operations"

Comment: @MattMcNabb I just realized, getc will not work completely for what I am trying to accomplish. For example, it will work for chars because chars are one byte, but what if I were to read a file with numbers as well? Is there a way I can take an input and break it down to it's lowest possible data type in C? And then do an XOR operation, such as (ch1 ^ ch2) == 0 to check if they are equal

Comment: "I was told: "==" is NOT a byte-by-byte comparison" -- you were presumably told this about ARRAYS ... == is perfectly fine for comparing individual bytes as you are doing here. "I just realized, getc will not work completely" -- As I noted elsewhere, you are very confused ... getc works fine. " it's lowest possible data type in C" -- which is `char`.

Answer (score 2):

In example 2, you aren't checking for end of file. That's why it never stops.

You are comparing byte by byte. I think both versions will be fine once you fix the second version.

Another couple things you might consider:

- If this may run on a Windows machine, use "rb" instead of "r" so that Windows won't convert line ending characters.
- You might want to add a ferror() test as well as the EOF. You won't usually need it, but I normally include it just in case.

Comment: Your problem with example 1 is incorrect. If one file is shorter, the character comparison will fail, because only one of them will be EOF.

Comment: @MikePrecup thanks, how might I be able to change that?

Comment: Also, is there a way I can possibly implement the percentage of the two files are identical?

Comment: @humblebeast you can fix that by using the minimum of `read1` and `read2`.

Comment: @humblebeast The issue was with his answer on example 1, not with your code. He's since fixed his answer. If you'd like to check what percentage of the files are identical, I'd recommend looking into diff algorithms, as they'll give you better results if the changes between the files are different lengths.